# Procedure fails with error 'SybaseErrorProcess'

Tags: sql, sybase

I receive `SybaseErrorProcess` whenever I run the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROC stdCont(@Cpty_Id INTEGER,  @TradeDate DATETIME) AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Ktest..FwdCont
    (Txn_No NUMERIC(10) IDENTITY, Deals_Id INTEGER NULL, Amount FLOAT NULL,OptionDate DATETIME NULL)

    insert into Ktest..FwdCont (Deals_Id ,Amount  ) (select Deals_Ids,amt from Ktest..trans)
    Update Ktest..FwdCont Set OptionDate = @TradeDate Where Deals_Id = @Cpty_Id

    select bk.tnxno,bk.bk.dealid ,fd.OptionDate ,fd.Amount    from Ktest..bakwnd bk ,Ktest..FwdCont fd where bk.dealid=fd.Deals_Id  and bk.op_date=fd.OptionDate

    DROP TABLE Ktest..FwdCont 
end
```

The error log reads as follows

```
number(2714) severity(16) state(1) line(9)
Connection Id:920 [raj@PROD-plus]
Server PLUS_ser
Procedure stdCont
Message string There is already an object named 'FwdCont' in the database.


*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54): SybaseErrorProcess

BEGIN SQL-REQUEST:
Ktest..stdCont 71495,  "07/25/2013"
END SQL-REQUEST


*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54):
Cannot perform your action:
Server Message:
         number(12336) severity(16) state(1) line(40)
        Connection Id:920 [raj@PROD-plus]
Server PLUS_ser
Procedure stdCont
Message string Definition time object 'database 'Ktest' (5), object 'FwdCont' (1974935499)' found at run time as an attempt to drop the table had failed i
n a previous query. Please drop the above mentioned table using the DROP TABLE c
ommand.

*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54): SybaseErrorProcess

BEGIN SQL-REQUEST:
Ktest..stdCont 71495,  "07/25/2013"
END SQL-REQUEST

*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54):
Cannot perform your action:
Server Message:
         number(12336) severity(16) state(1) line(40)
        Connection Id:920 [raj@PROD-plus]
Server PLUS_ser
Procedure stdCont
Message string Definition time object 'database 'Ktest' (5), object 'FwdCont' (1974935499)' found at run time as an attempt to drop the table had failed i
n a previous query. Please drop the above mentioned table using the DROP TABLE c
ommand.


*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54): SybaseErrorProcess

BEGIN SQL-REQUEST:
Ktest..stdCont 71495,  "07/25/2013"
END SQL-REQUEST

*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54):
Cannot perform your action:
Server Message:
         number(12336) severity(16) state(1) line(40)
        Connection Id:920 [raj@PROD-plus]
Server PLUS_ser
Procedure stdCont
Message string Definition time object 'database 'Ktest' (5), object 'FwdCont' (1974935499)' found at run time as an attempt to drop the table had failed i
n a previous query. Please drop the above mentioned table using the DROP TABLE c
ommand.

*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54): SybaseErrorProcess

BEGIN SQL-REQUEST:
Ktest..stdCont 71495,  "07/25/2013"
END SQL-REQUEST


*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54):
Cannot perform your action:
Server Message:
         number(12336) severity(16) state(1) line(40)
        Connection Id:920 [raj@PROD-plus]
Server PLUS_ser
Procedure stdCont
Message string Definition time object 'database 'Ktest' (5), object 'FwdCont' (1974935499)' found at run time as an attempt to drop the table had failed i
n a previous query. Please drop the above mentioned table using the DROP TABLE c
ommand.

*** Error(Fri 26 Jul 2013 - 18:21:54):
Cannot perform your action:
Server Message:
         number(11060) severity(16) state(1) line(40)
        Connection Id:920 [raj@PROD-plus]
Server PLUS_ser
Procedure stdCont
Message string This statement has exceeded the maximum number of recompilations
(10). This indicates an internal error. Please note the error prior to this one
and contact Sybase Technical Support.
```

Maybe it is a deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear!

You already have the `FwdCont` table in your database, probably because of an old execution of your stored procedure.

Comment: Thand for reply, but end of procedure i drop FwdCont table. then why show error

Comment: May be the last run didn't execute successfully, better to add a check if the table exists before creating it.

Comment: How to avoid this issue.. If any one solution pl. inform me

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: Sybase, I found the solution . we create #table i.e temporary table instead of physical table. it's doesn't throw a error.